# Android notification view long text?

Tags: android, notifications

my notification is ok in small text like "Hi everybody?", but when it  is a sentence that cant   fit in the screen size, i dont see it. is there any way around? I am having a really hard time to get  how to do it.. is remote view the way to go?

Comment: I think that there isn't a way to do this. Anyway, Android will roll the text when the cursor is selecting this notification.

Comment: notification means Action bar(topbar) or Dialog notification ?

Comment: topbar/status bar
how will it roll? when i select it, the status bar will return to its not-expanded state. i didnt put auto_cancel